# Integrate Hyperpay Payment for Android

Tags: android, payment

I need to integrate Hyperpay for Android, then check out their documentation:
https://hyperpay.docs.oppwa.com/tutorials/mobile-sdk/first-integration

As mentioned in the above link

> Add the Mobile SDK for Android.
> Drag and drop oppwa.mobile.aar & ipworks3ds_sdk.aar (use ipworks3ds_sdk_deploy.aar for production) to the "libs" folder of the module where you plan to integrate Mobile SDK. In the build.gradle file of this module add:

So, How can I download the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to contact Hyperpay team to provide you with their SDK. They can't just put their SDK download url to the public. Its provided per merchant. They usually send it via email.